# How to get data from google fit and iOS HealthKit in Flutter

Tags: flutter, healthkit, google-fit

I want to get data like number of steps, heart rate and cal. from google fit and iOS HealthKit to Flutter App

Answer (score 0):

You can use health 3.4.3
Install by readme.
Link:
https://pub.dev/packages/health